# Password protection by .htaccess file not working after deployment on a new server

Tags: passwords, dedicated

I migrated my application to a new server (from a VPS to a dedicated) yesterday and the password protection which was working correctly on the previous server (using .htaccess file - asking username/pass) doesn't work anymore : anyone can access the website without being asked to enter a username pass. I don't really have a clue why it's not working anymore as I kept everything the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Apache config, you'll need `AllowOverride` not to be set to `None`.